# Voisin exercise 2.2 on degrees

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to solve the following exercise from Voisin's Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry:

***Exercise 2**: Let $X$ be  compact complex curve (Riemann surface) and let $f$ be a non-constant meromorphic function on $X$.*

*(a) Show that we can view $f$ as a holomorphic map from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$*

For this, I think we can just send the poles of $f$ to the point at infinity.

*(b) Let $t$ be a point of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $D$ be a disk in $\mathbb{P}^1$ centred at $t$. Using exercise 3(c) of chapter 1, show that
$$n_t=\int_{f^{-1}(\partial D)}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\frac{df}{f-t}$$
is equal to the number of points of the fibre $f^{-1}(t)$, counted with the multiplicities given by the order of vanishing $k_x(f-t)$.*

The exercise mentioned says that $k_x(f)=\int_D \frac{1}{2i\pi}\frac{df}{f}$, where $D$ is a disk that contains only one pole or zero, namely $x$. I think the exercise will be solved if I can somehow replace $f^{-1}(\partial D)$ by small circles around the fibres of $t$, but am not sure how this could be done.

*(c) Show that $n_t$ is independent of $t$*

A few questions and ideas: what can we say about $f^{-1}(\partial D)$? I think it should be some 1-dimensional submanifold of $X$ and then maybe one can use something like Stokes' theorem to show that it is homologous to all the small circles around the fibres. But I am not sure whether it is connected and what exactly it bounds (maybe the Jordan curve theorem can be used?).  Also, do inverse images commute with boundaries, i.e. $f^{-1}(\partial D)=\partial f^{-1}(D)$? Lastly, what would be a way to show independence of $t$? Intuitively, a small perturbation shouldn't change the integral - perhaps one can differentiate w.r.t. t and get $0$?

Comment: (b) is some kind of the argument principle. Locally $D$ can be samll enough to make it's homeomorphic to its preimage(maybe more than one circles). The independence can be showed by $X$ is (path) connected maybe (and the fact that $f^{-1}(p)$ is descrete, finite in the compact case for any $p \in \Bbb{P}$ I think).

Comment: A revision for the upper comment: $f^{-1}(\partial D)$ is composed by some simple closed curves. $D$ maybe not homeomorphic to each of the components. Taking $f(z)=z^2$ as an example, for small disk $D$ center at $0$, $f^{-1}(\partial D)$ contains one loop and  for small disk $D$ center at $1$, $f^{-1}(\partial D)$ contains two loop.